# python: extracting values from csv file by row name

Tags: python, csv

Consider a .csv file with the following format:

```
John,29,21,,DF,
Sara,23,51,,DF,
John,34,27,,ER,
John,76,29,,TY,
Sara,87,93,,SAD,
```

I need to retrieve the value in the second column for all the rows which have 'John' written in the first column. I want to do it using a python script. I'm very new to python so I'm asking how can this be done?

Comment: Take a look at the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Are there really spaces after the commas in your input CSV file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you're right, there are no spaces. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) makes this trivial:

```
import csv

with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == 'John':
            print row[1]
```

This assumes that you are using Python 2. The Python 3 version looks like:

```
import csv

with open(inputfilename, newline='') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == 'John':
            print(row[1])
```